# Merging to table from 2 joined tables

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, merge

For example I am having two tables with id,age,status and height. And there is a table  RESULT which I need to merge to.

### Table 1

```
*id age status*
1  15   1
2  16   1
3  17   0
```

### Table 2

```
*id height*
1  160
2  170
3  180
```

And Result table is:

### Result table

```
*id age height*
1  15   160
```

I need to insert into Result table id,height,age from Table 1 join Table 2 on ID ,where status is 1.

How can I write something like

```
Merge into Result
USING(Select ... from Table1
join Table2 on Table1.id=Table2.id where status=1)
When Not Matched THEN
Insert into Result VALUES(Table1.id,age,height)
```

I need to get

### RESULT

```
*id age height*
1   15   160
2   16   170
```

So how can I implement that merge which will  find user with id=2 in Result

Table and Insert and will not Insert user with id=1 because it is already in table?

Comment: MYSQL does not have merge or MATCHED is this purely an Oracle question or are you looking for a mysql alternate.

Comment: I am guessing based on the syntax that you are using Oracle, so I removed the MySQL tag.

Comment: missclicked when was choosing tags,yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
MERGE INTO RESULT R USING (
                              SELECT
                                  T1.ID,
                                  T1.AGE,
                                  T1.STATUS,
                                  T2.HEIGHT
                              FROM
                                  TABLE1 T1
                                  JOIN TABLE2 T2 ON T1.ID = T2.ID
                              WHERE
                                  STATUS = 1
                          ) DATAA 
ON ( R.ID = DATAA.ID ) 
WHEN NOT MATCHED 
THEN INSERT (
    ID,
    AGE,
    HEIGHT ) 
    VALUES (
    DATAA.ID,
    DATAA.AGE,
    DATAA.HEIGHT )
```

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

Below is the sql query in need to run whole query together

insert into result
Select t1.Id, t1.Age, t2.Height from Table1 t1 inner join Table2 t2 on t1.Id=t2.Id where t1.status=1

Comment: there will be duplicates into result table 
if there were some lines before with same id,age,height. Like id=1 in my example

WIth such query I will get two lines with
id=1,age=15,height=160

Comment: Your Id is not primary key ?

Comment: its just a simple example of task, in my current issue there is large table with difficult primary key.
So there is only way to merge or to try insert id's which are not in table already

Comment: Then you have to find duplicate id and remove that. you can use CTE for that to finding duplicate and remove it by ID

Comment: But it wil be full scan,so it will work too long and use too much memory with large table